# WSLENV maps APPDATA but not HOMEPATH

Tags: windows-10, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the `HOMEPATH` and `APPDATA` environment variables in Windows:

[image]

I have tried to map these through to my WSL/Debian environment using `WSLENV`:

[image]

However, when I try to inspect these variables in Debian I only see one of them:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`WSLENV` can only map absolute paths apparently, not relative paths. This WSL issue explains this:

[image]
Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1494